# Java: JDOQL startsWith query, case sensitive

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus, jdoql

I'm using the .startsWith() filter in a JDOQL query but it's case sensitive.
So startsWith("ab") doesn't return "Abc" result and so on.

Will I need to use a SQL query to avoid this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So combine it with toUpperCase() then perhaps
field.toUpperCase().startsWith("AB")

Edit : fix method names

Comment: omg why didn't I think of combining like with any extensions methods. I feel really dumb now. The methods name are toUpperCase()/toLowerCase().
Thanks

Comment: Simple rule for JDOQL : think how you would express a condition in Java, and then check that all methods and operators are available in JDOQL - they usually are.